# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with box2d and b2body

Tags: c++, objective-c

I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS accessing a b2body from a b2fixture. This will likely be due to my lack of knowledge in c++, since I'm an ObjC dev mixing in c++ (just started with box2d):

```
Myb2dUserData.h
@interface Myb2dUserData : NSObject {
    MyContact *climbingHoldContact;  
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) MyContact *climbingHoldContact;

Myb2dUserData.mm
    b2Fixture *fixA = climbingHoldContact->fixtureA;
    b2Body *bodA = fixA->GetBody(); //EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

I assign the climbingHoldContact in a b2ContactListener, which is pretty much a copy from this code:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/505/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-22

```
void MyContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) {


    MyContact myContact = { contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB() };
    _contacts.push_back(myContact);

    b2Fixture *fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
    b2Body *bodyA = fixtureA->GetBody();
    Myb2dUserData *userDataA = (Myb2dUserData *)bodyA->GetUserData();
    bodyHoldUD.climbingHoldContact = &myContact;
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: add more checks for NULL pointers

Answer (score 0):

This variable, `myContact`, is local to `BeginContact`:

```
MyContact myContact = { contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB() };
```

But here, you're storing a pointer to it for future reference:

```
bodyHoldUD.climbingHoldContact = &myContact;
```

When `BeginContact` returns, the `myContact` variable ceases to exist, and when you later attempt to access its `fixtureA` your computer says `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` because whatever was there has been overwritten with something else.
This is the same problem as returning a pointer to a local variable.

Note that the example you built on stores `MyContact`s in the vector, not `MyContact*`s.

You should be able to fix this one by just changing the `climbingHoldContact` member to not be a pointer.